# On Karl Popper's criterion of falsifiability, vs. verifiability

Tags: falsifiability, demarcation

Karl Popper famously said that falsifiability is the distinguishing criterion of science. However, what about statements that are not falsifiable, but verifiable, that is, there is an observation or potential observation that can verify the statement as true. For example, the statement "Zebras exist" is not falsifiable, but it is verifiable, because an observation of zebras can verify the statement as true. So, was Karl Popper wrong in saying that falsifiability of a statement is what distinguishes science from non-science? Maybe the real distinguishing criterion is the disjunction of falsifiability with verifiability? Or have I simply misunderstood what falsifiable means?

Comment: Falsifiability is a meaningful "local" test for some (many) propositions, and it *was* worth Popper's time to emphasize it. But too much could be, and was, made of it, just the same. It is perhaps likely that words/phrases like "science" and "the scientific method" cannot be fully pinned down by some neat, tidy little analysis; on the other hand, again, this is not to say that falsification (or verification) tests are absolutely useless, either, in this context.

Comment: I don't know if anything has been achieved with "trueifiable", because "zebras exist" = "not (zebras don't exist)", and "zebras don't exist" is falsifiable ...

Comment: Popper characterized the works of science as producing universal as opposed to existential statements. Universal statements about the world can be falsified but not verified; existential statements about the world can be verified but not falsified.

Comment: @DavidGudeman if you could expand that comment into a full answer, I think you'd have a pretty conclusive answer to the OP question as it stands. Or, hopefully the OP poster would accept your answer, then. —Now, re: that poster/post, I am going to edit "trueifiability" to "verifiability," please don't take my edit as a hostile move, but the prefix "veri-" does usually go with "falsi-" in this kind of context (e.g. "veridical/falsidical").

Comment: @KristianBerry, OK, I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scientific statements Popper was interested in are what are called lawlike statements such as Newton's Law of Gravity. If you put the Law of Gravity into fully quantified form, it looks something like this

> (∀m1,m2)f(m1,m2)=G(m1+m2)/r(m1,m2)

where m1 and m2 range over masses, f(m1,m2) is the force between m1 and m2, r(m1,m2) is the distance between m1 and m2, and G is the gravitational constant.

Notice that this is an unrestricted universal quantification. It applies to all objects of the correct type that ever have or ever will exist. All lawlike statements are unrestricted universally quantified statements. By contrast, "zebras exist" is not a universal statement; it is an existential statement.

Empirical data is neither universal nor existential. Such unquantified statements are often called basic statements. For example, suppose you measure the force between two masses, x and y. The result of the experiment would be expressed as the basic statement

> f(x,y) = F

for some force F. Given the above statement, you can check whether or not F=G(x+y)/r(x,y). If the equality fails, then you have falsified the universal law (ignoring issues of precision and experimental error). If the equality succeeds, then you have not verified the law, because there could still be other experiments that could falsify it. Logically, no matter how many experiments you do, you can never verify this universal statement, because there will always be pairs of masses you have not checked.

By contrast if you have an existential statement like "zebras exist", then a basic statement like "that is a zebra" can verify this statement, but no humanly possible collection of basic statements can falsify that zebras exist; you would have to examine every object in the universe to determine that it is not a zebra.

This is a general principle of logic: a basic statement can falsify a universal statement or verify an existential statement, but no humanly possible basic statement can verify an unrestricted universal statement or falsify an unrestricted existential statement.

I added "unrestricted" because suitably limited universal statements can be verified by a basic statement and suitably limited existential statements can be falsified by a basic statement. For example:

> All of the coins in my pocket are of the same denomination

or

> There is a nickel in my pocket.

These are restricted quantifications, which changes the situation considerably.

So the answer to your question is that Popper promoted falsification rather than verification because lawlike statements are unrestricted universal statements and empirical observations are basic statements, so no empirical observation can verify a scientific law, but an empirical observation can falsify a scientific law.